# I am getting org.apache.http.MalformedChunkCodingException: CRLF expected at end of chunk error in android internet app

Tags: android

I am trying to access the internet from my application.

> We are using proxy in our company, so i entered the proxy settings for the simulator by using the -http-proxy XXXXX.
>
> I added the android.permission.INTERNET in android manifest file as well.
>
> When i am trying to access the internet i am getting this exception and my application is getting force closed.

Note: When i am using the browser application in the Emulator, i am able to access the internet.

I just copy pasted this code
http://w3mentor.com/learn/java/android-development/android-http-services/example-of-http-get-request-using-httpclient-in-android/

I am getting the error:
**WARN/System.err(300): org.apache.http.MalformedChunkCodingException: CRLF expected at end of chunk**

Please help me in resolving the same.

Thanks & Regards,
SSuman185

Comment: Can you show the code for the client constructor and setup?  It sounds like you are expecting chunked-encoding but your web service is not sending chunked-encoded data.

Answer (score 2):

Change buffer size in jmeter properties.

Sample: buffer size is `800`. Multiply it by `30%` so `240.` Edit the **buffer size to 240**.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. How to increase buffer size and where to increase?

Answer (score 0):

may be this [issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2168) can help you.